# createMaterialTopTabNavigator tabs stop moving on press after slide

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am using createMaterialTopTabNavigator from React-navigation in my application. i am facing two problems :

1) BY default tabs where changing and moving on swipe , but i wanted them to move and change when i press the tab items , so i added following code

```
tabBarOnPress: (scene, jumpToIndex) => {      
    jumpToIndex(scene.index);
  }
```

but now when i launch app , the tabs get change on click , however as soon as i change by slide, changing on click stops.

2) I want to change active tab labelstyle to bold , any help on how to do so

```
labelStyle: {
      textAlign: 'center'              
    }
```

Comment: Bold text can be done via `fontWeight: 'bold'`

Comment: @zaytrix how to check focus here?

Comment: You will likely have to override the `tabBarComponent` to achieve focus specific styling other than tint color, here is the source code for the `tabBarComponent` that `createMaterialTopTabNavigator` uses: https://github.com/react-navigation/tabs/blob/master/src/views/MaterialTopTabBar.js